# re-shaping dataframe with custom requirements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
    Node ID11 ID10  ID9 ID8 ID7 ID6 ID5 ID4 ID3 ID2 ID1 ID0
0   YYZ     1    2    3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   DFW     4    5    6  7  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   DEN    20   21  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   BOS   100  101  102 103 104 105 106 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

I want to re-shape it such that the end result looks like:

```
    Node num1 num2
0   YYZ    3    2
1   YYZ    3    1
2   DFW    7    6
3   DFW    7    5
4   DFW    7    4
5   DEN   21   20
6   BOS  106  105
7   BOS  106  104
8   BOS  106  103
9   BOS  106  102
10  BOS  106  101
11  BOS  106  100
```

Basically, the last non nan ID in a row for a Node goes in column one and then every other ID goes in column 2 and in subsequent rows for the same Node.

I've been playing around with the functions (stack/unstack) built into pandas but so far haven't been able to shape it right. My actual dataframe is huge so right now just playing with a test frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#change order of columns for change ordering of final value column
df = df[df.columns[::-1]]

#reshape by stack
df = (df.set_index('Node')
        .stack()
        .rename_axis(('Node','num1'))
        .astype(int)
        .reset_index(name='num2'))

#get last non NaN value to num1 column
df['num1'] = df.groupby('Node')['num2'].transform('first')
#remove last row per groups
df = df[df.duplicated(subset=['Node'])].copy()
print (df)
   Node  num1  num2
1   YYZ     3     2
2   YYZ     3     1
4   DFW     7     6
5   DFW     7     5
6   DFW     7     4
8   DEN    21    20
10  BOS   106   105
11  BOS   106   104
12  BOS   106   103
13  BOS   106   102
14  BOS   106   101
15  BOS   106   100
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, I am using  `wide_to_long` before that we need do some adjustment in our original df, which is `idxmax` for find the last valid value

```
s=df.notnull().iloc[:,::-1].idxmax(1)
df['num1']=df.lookup(df.index,s)
df['check']=s.str.strip('ID')
s=pd.wide_to_long(df,'ID',['Node','num1','check'],j='drop').dropna().reset_index()
s=s.loc[s.check!=s.drop,['ID','num1','Node']]

s

Out[459]: 
       ID   num1 Node
0     1.0    3.0  YYZ
1     2.0    3.0  YYZ
3     4.0    7.0  DFW
4     5.0    7.0  DFW
5     6.0    7.0  DFW
7    20.0   21.0  DEN
9   100.0  106.0  BOS
10  101.0  106.0  BOS
11  102.0  106.0  BOS
12  103.0  106.0  BOS
13  104.0  106.0  BOS
14  105.0  106.0  BOS
```

Comment: @jezrael yes checking it . one sec

Answer (score 2):

I would use `stack` and `groupby`:

```
new_df = df.set_index('Node').stack().to_frame(name='num2')
groups = new_df.groupby('Node')
new_df['num1'] = groups['num2'].transform('last')
new_df = new_df.drop(groups.tail(1).index)
```

Output:

```
            num2   num1
Node                   
YYZ  ID11    1.0    3.0
     ID10    2.0    3.0
DFW  ID11    4.0    7.0
     ID10    5.0    7.0
     ID9     6.0    7.0
DEN  ID11   20.0   21.0
BOS  ID11  100.0  106.0
     ID10  101.0  106.0
     ID9   102.0  106.0
     ID8   103.0  106.0
     ID7   104.0  106.0
     ID6   105.0  106.0
```